# Android - How to create a html textarea-like EditText

Tags: java, android

I want to get input from the user it can be a paragraph also. so i need the editText box with scrollable option.
I want something like this
 [image]

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 4):

use

```
            android:minLines="3"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

in EditText Layout.

It will provide you a textarea with minimum 3 Lines

Answer (score 4):

You can create it by setting vertical scroll bars. Use below code:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/textArea_information"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@null"
android:gravity="top|left"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:overScrollMode="always"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:lines="6"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
```

You might face issue while using this textArea inside scroll view. 
Reference: https://learnpainless.com/android/how-to-create-textarea-in-android